# Is there a way to ignore Handlebars templates within a Handlebars template?

Tags: node.js, handlebars.js

I'm using Express + Handlebars in my server side node application, and I want to send client templates to the browser as part of the page that I'm rendering.

index.html

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>{{title}}</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div>
    {{stuff}}    
  </div>
  <script id="more-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    <div>{{more}}</div>
  </script>
</body>
```

Unfortunately, handlebars tries to render the stuff in the #more-template script block. (Which just removes the `{{more}}` because it's undefined in the server template's context.

**Is there a way I can get it to ignore the stuff inside the script tag?** (So that the client side template can use it)

I already saw this question: [Node.js with Handlebars.js on server and client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10037936/node-js-with-handlebars-js-on-server-and-client), I'd rather just use 1 template engine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So I didn't find a way to ignore client templates easily, but the general consensus is to precompile your client templates.

1. Install handlebars globally `npm install handlebars -g`
2. Precompile your templates `handlebars client-template1.handlebars -f templates.js`
3. Include templates.js `<script src="templates.js"></script>`
4. Execute the template `var html = Handlebars.templates["client-template1"](context);`

Extra info
[Using pre-compiled templates with Handlebars.js (jQuery Mobile environment)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8659787/using-pre-compiled-templates-with-handlebars-js-jquery-mobile-environment)
http://handlebarsjs.com/precompilation.html

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. after juggling a lot of places, I found this the easiest and the best working solution for my stuff.

Answer (score 11):

In General, when your template is being compiled two times (e.g. when you are only server-side) and you want to ignore template tags in the first run, you can simply tell handlebars to ignore them by appending a backslash:

```
{{variable1}} \{{variable2}}
```

When compiling with `variable1` set to `value1` and `variable2` being undefined, you get:

```
value1 {{variable2}}
```

(instead of getting the second tag replaced with empty string).

When compiling the second run with `variable2` set to `value2`, you get:

```
value1 value2
```

Not the perfect solution (which would be a setting for Handlebars to leave undefined variables alone), but working for my special case.

Comment: This. Was. Helpful.
Related post I made just in case:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66533653/multiple-pass-variable-replacements-with-handlebars/66534342#66534342