# Love handlebars.js loath HTML

Tags: haml, handlebars.js, pug, slim-lang

Anyone know of mash-ups of templating languages (Jade, Slim, etc) and handlebars.js? I really hate using raw HTML. I want to stick with handlebars.js as I already have a large set of production code in use with it.

Comment: Related? [Node.js with Handlebars.js on server and client](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13874161/is-there-a-way-to-ignore-handlebars-templates-within-a-handlebars-template/13884587#13884587) and [Is there a way to ignore Handlebars templates within a Handlebars template?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10037936/node-js-with-handlebars-js-on-server-and-client#answer-13884683)