# multiple pass variable replacements with handlebars?

Tags: javascript, sed, replace, handlebars.js, mustache

I haven't found a decent answer to this yet, so I figure I'll try.

Use-case. I have HTML files that will require 2 passes of processing. One of them has static variables in it, but I need them replaced on compile time with fixed values for multiple tiers (dev, intermediary, production).

I also have a set of variables that will get replaced when a template like this is downloaded, which would be the second pass.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    ...stuff
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello {{ReplaceOnCompile}}</h1>
    <a href="{{ReplaceOnRuntime}}">Some Link</a>
  </body>
</html>
```

As far as I know, Handlebars doesn't provide any way out of the box to do this. I currently have the system working using the following:

```
// Create handlebars object from template
const template = await compile(rawFileContents)

// Replace template with variables
const html = await template({
  ReplaceOnRunTime: 'foo'
})
```

Thats all good and dandy, but that leaves me with:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    ...stuff
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello </h1>
    <a href="foo">Some Link</a>
  </body>
</html>
```

I don't see anything in its docs that supports custom delimiters/wrapper experessions to do a pass one/pass two kind of thing.

My next idea is to use `sed` or just a package like this to do the first pass replacements:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/replace-in-file

And in the template, use a different syntax for each type of variable to replace:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    ...stuff
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello {<<ReplaceOnCompile>>}</h1> // Pass this through one replacement func
    <a href="{{ReplaceOnRuntime}}">Some Link</a> // Pass this through a second one.
  </body>
</html>
```

Not sure the best approach to this, as I'm trying to avoid using two different libraries for essentially the same task, just staggered.

Answer (score 2):

I found a neat way to escape them!

https://repl.it/@nicholashazel/TriflingMeanLogin

You can escape a handlebars expression and have it output the raw `{{variableName}}` by simply using a backslash.

#### Pass 1

```html
<body>
  <h1>{{ReplaceMe}}</h1>
  <p>\{{DontReplaceMe}}</p>
</body>
```

```js
const variables = {
  ReplaceMe: 'Replaced in pass 1'
}
const template = await handlebars.compile(data)
const html = await template(variables)
```

```html
<body>
  <h1>Replaced in pass 1</h1>
  <p>{{DontReplaceMe}}</p>
</body>
```

#### Pass 2

```js
const newVariables = {
  DontReplaceMe: 'Replaced in pass 2'
}
const newTemplate = await handlebars.compile(html)
const newHtml = await newTemplate(newVariables)
```

```html
<body>
  <h1>Replaced in pass 1</h1>
  <p>Replaced in pass 2</p>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems a strange use-case to me, however, I think I would solve it by setting the values of my runtime variables to be Handlebars expressions, ensuring to preserve the variable name.

This means the data object used in the first execution of the template would include the following:

```
ReplaceOnRuntime: "{{ReplaceOnRuntime}}"
```

Which would mean that `{{ReplaceOnRuntime}}` in my template, would get replaced with "{{ReplaceOnRuntime}}" - in other words, the template input and output for this expression would be identical.

I have created an example [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/76484/wke6f0j9/) for reference.

Comment: I see where you're going with this. Yeah, the use case is that some initial variables I need replaced dynamically when we SAVE the template, and the other ones are filled in with account specific things when we CONSUME the template.