# Handlebar template is not able to read the data passed

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

I am new to handlebar and am stuck at rendering a template via a handlebar script. Below is the code. The output doesn't contain the object attribute that i pass to the template. Please help!

```
    <script   src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/4.0.4/handlebars.js">  </script>
    <script>
    var context = { "name" : "XYZ", "occupation" : "developer" };

    var templateScript = $('#handlebars-demo').html();
    var theTemplate = Handlebars.compile(templateScript);
    var html = theTemplate({name: "XYZ",occupation: "developer"});
    console.log(html);
    $(document.body).append(html);
</script>
<script id="handlebars-demo" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
<div>
    My name is {{name}}. I am a {{occupation}}. // This just just renders My name is . I am a .
</div>
```

Comment: works as expected http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Wxyxdz

Comment: It sill doesnt work in my app.. Has it got to do anything with the way I use handlebars in my node app?

Comment: Same here. https://jsfiddle.net/3hjLztom/ Any errors in the browser console?

Comment: Being a node app you will have to register handlebars as your view engine

Comment: I have set it as my view engine. I have rendered a few pages using this already but now I tried to dynamically load up data and it creates a problem.

     app.set('view engine', 'hbs');

Answer (score 5):

I was having the same problem, when using handlebar with node js.

The problem is when you create a **handlebar template**, it will **pre-compile** your script with the **server-side compiler using it's context** (response from the server).
So the **templateScript** variable which **doesn't have name and occupation yet in the context**, will look something like this :

```
<div>
    My name is . I am a .
</div>
```

There are a couple of solution to avoid this:

- **add `\{{` to escape the expression**

> ```
> <script id="handlebars-demo" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
>     <div>
>         My name is \{{name}}. I am a \{{occupation}}.
>     </div>
> </script>
> ```

- **pre-compile your client-side script separately.**

**For more information, checkout the below link:**
[Node.js with Handlebars.js on server and client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10037936/node-js-with-handlebars-js-on-server-and-client)

Answer (score 1):

Try `{{context.name}}` and `{{context.occupation}}`

Comment: It still doesn't work. Is there something I need to with the config on my node app? Its a node app. Sorry, i should have mentioned that first.